# serving angularjs pages with node

Tags: angularjs, node.js, routes

I'm trying to serve an angularjs page with nodejs.

The index.html works if i just open it up with the browser:-

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="ex1">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ang-ex1</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#AddNewOrder"> Add New Order </a></li>
                <li><a href="#ShowOrders"> Show Order </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('ex1', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/AddNewOrder', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/add_order.html',
            controller: 'AddOrderController'
        }).
        when('/ShowOrders', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/show_orders.html',
            controller: 'ShowOrderController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/AddNewOrder'
        });
}]);
app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
}]);
app.controller('AddOrderController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.message = 'Add Order Scope'; 
}]);
app.controller('ShowOrderController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.message = 'Show Order Scope';    
}]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**templates/add_order.html**

```
 <h2>Add New Order</h2>

 {{ message }}
```

**templates/show_orders.html**

```
 <h2>Show Orders</h2>

 {{ message }}
```

I am trying to serve the page with the following nodejs server

**server.js**

```
/*jshint node:true*/
/*jshint esnext:true*/
'use strict';

var koa = require('koa')();
var router = require('koa-router')();
var views = require('co-views');
var render = views('.', {map: {html: 'swig'}});

router.get('/', function *(next) {
    this.body = yield render('index');
});

koa.use(router.routes());

koa.listen(8080);
```

the page loads but clicking on the links doesn't load my angularjs templates.

How can I fix my nodejs routing to make it work?

Comment: are you able to see any errors in console..?

Answer (score 0):

ngView uses client-side routing, so if index.html is loading fine then Node.js isn't your issue -- it's an Angular problem.

It appears that your URLs are not formatted correctly. Try "#/AddNewOrder" and "#/ShowOrders" in your hrefs.

Answer (score 0):

When you load the link `http://localhost:80/templates/add_order.html` (or whatever port you are using) do you get the raw source of your template ? Is so, then it is not a server-side koa problem. If you get nothing, then it is a koa problem.

I don't use the koa framework, but it doesn't look like you've associated the `render` thing with the `routes` thing, which I assume is required for koa to serve all your static files.